# CSS styling multiple elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

quick question regarding CSS. I am currently working on a project that has a few CSS files that style the pages. At the minute I am trying to figure the best way of re-styling several elements ie: (h1, h2, h3) that are contained within a specific div ie:

```
<container id=1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h2></h2>
</container>
```

The thing is these elements already have CSS properties, I am fine with overwriting them but is there a better way of doing it than:

```
#1 h1, #1 h2, #1 h3{styling}
```

I know a better option is to re-work the whole CSS, but it's more feasable at the current time to just make overwrites.

Comment: Note: HTML IDs must begin with a letter, not a number.

Comment: @ChristianVarga - well, technically in HTML5 [they can](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute). But it's probably not a bad idea to avoid it as some older browsers may not cope well.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez interesting, didn't know that! +1 for the comment!

Comment: @ChristianVarga - yeah, the new spec is incredibly permissive. I still find leaving out quotes/closing tags and including digits in IDs etc. a bit scary. But it's useful to know they're not invalid.

Comment: might sound stupid but, why would give you h1, h2, h3 the same style? ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're doing it right. The best way is just to make selectors that are more specific than the selectors that already exist.

`!important` is a hack that should be avoided at all costs, unless it is absolutely impossible to override the selector. In this case it isn't, so `!important` should be avoided.

You should also be aware that HTML IDs should not start with a number, they must start with a letter. And should be wrapped in quotes. Eg:

```
<container id="one">
  ...
</container>
```

Comment: Ah sweet, glad I am doing it correctly. Some long CSS property names incoming! And yep, just used that as an example (Really should type out valid HTML when asking for help)

Comment: Again, attribute quotes are optional in HTML5 - but for most purposes it's a good idea to include them. Nothing *technically* wrong with the OP's markup though.